# Suspend doesn't happen when laptop lid closes - awesome wm

Tags: power-management, awesome

I've installed awesome as my windows manager.
However, it doesn't seem to respect the power options from lightdm; if I'm at the login screen shutting the lid will trigger suspend.

Once I log into the awesome wm, however, this no longer happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It no longer happens because power management is different between lightdm and the the session you log in to. Each session is expected to handle its own power management, for various reasons, and so you will need to run a power manager with your WM to get this feature to work as you wish.

A good power manager for the task would be `xfce4-power-manager`, which you can get in the repos. You can set it to suspend when the lid is closed. Then, just set it to start with your awesome-wm session and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use package `pm-utils` from the repos, then issue the command `pm-suspend` (as root) to suspend the laptop, more info on this link http://goo.gl/emZFUB

```
apt-get install pm-utils
```

Also, if your latop has a 'suspend' button or a combination of keys such as `Fn`+`F3` to suspend /hibernate you can use them just make sure you have installed the packages `acpi-support` and `acpi-support-base`

```
apt-get install acpi-suport acpi-support-base
```

With this and some bits of configuration you can achieve to suspend the machine when the lid is closed (or using a button or combination of keys)